# Can't delete files inside zip archive

Tags: archive-mode

windows 10, emacs 26.1

In dired mode I enter a zip archive by press `enter`

Nice.

Now I want to delete one file and one dir inside archive. I mark it by `d` and press `x` . 
But I get this error:

```
No such file or directory, zip
```

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't related to `dired`, as archives aren't opened by it in default, and even your screenshot clearly shows that you're dealing with a different major mode.

Comment: The error message suggests you don't have the `zip` program installed on your system, or Emacs is looking for it in the wrong place.

Comment: @Tyler Your comment qualifies as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Searching for program: No such file or directory, zip

This suggests that Emacs can't find the `zip` program. Perhaps it's not installed on your system, or is in a non-standard location.